# Authentication failure when access storage blob from Azure Service

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-blob-storage, azure-cloud-services

We have Cloud service extended support (worker role) which processes data (read/write/append/list etc) in Storage Blob.
When it had Networking/Public network access set to 'Enabled from all networks' everything worked, but after changing to
'Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses' we getting error    
'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException This request is not authorized to perform this operation'
on all CloudBlockBlob methods (ExistsAsync,UploadFromByteArrayAsync,DownloadToStreamAsync etc.)

Cloud service accesses Storage using App Registration xxx which creates tocken to get Storage Access Key from  Key Vault
App Registration xxx has roles Storage Account Contributor and Storage Blob Data Contributor

Added Storage Blob Data Owner on Container:
storageaccount -> container -> Access control rules -> add role assignement -> Storage Blob Data Owner -> selected App Registration xxx

Added Cloud service IP and local (VPN's) IP.

Local works fine, Cloud service still has authentication error.

Comment: Could you please share the detailed error which includes exception callstack and then failing `x-ms-requestid` header ( GUID which ends with 6 zeros) ?

Comment: Error attempting storage operation on container xxx for storage account zzz: AuthorizationFailure. Request is ignored.,
"EXCEPTION OCCURRED:Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException 
This request is not authorized to perform this operation
Request Information
RequestID:0b3b4ab9-e01e-0039-70a3-c03585000000
RequestDate:Thu, 27 Jul 2023 16:00:01 GMT
StatusMessage:This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
ErrorCode:AuthorizationFailure
ErrorMessage:This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
RequestId:0b3b4ab9-e01e-0039-70a3-c03585000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the detailed error message with the `x-ms-requestID`. The 403 error failure is due to the IP Authorization failure. We could see an ipv6 address reaching the storage FE layer. This typically happens while the VNET has the service endpoint enabled. Could you please follow [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/how-to-set-blob-storage-firewall-accessing-from-app-service-only/ba-p/3638851) blog and check if that helps ? Also ensure that you have Added that subnet of that VNET in the storage account as shown below ?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Gave full information about reason and ways to fix.